angular/jenkins build api cors issue
I am trying to invoke jenkins build api from angular, where as i get cors issue.
I installed cors filter plugin in my jenkins to access from my local host, and updated the plugin as below.
``Access-Control-Allow-Origins:http://localhost:4200/
Access-Control-Allow-Header- Authorization, origin, content-type, accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept-Encoding, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Accept-Language
The same api works fine with curl and postman,
``
Can you please review for any help on this,
